# Playground for Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

In school, one of my professors had created a 3D game (not just an engine), where all the players were entirely AI-controlled, and it was our assignment to program the AI of a single player. We were basically provided an API to interact with the game world.

Our AI implementations were then dropped into the game together, and we watched as our programs went to battle against each other.

It was like [robot soccer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCup), but virtual, with lots of big guns, and no soccer ball.

I'm now looking for anything similar (and **open source**) to play with. (Preferably in Java, but I'm open to any language.) I'm *not* looking for a game engine, or a framework... I'm looking for a complete game that simply lacks AI code... preferably set up for this kind of exercise. Suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds very similar to [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/).

> Robocode is a programming game, where the goal is to develop a robot battle tank to battle against other tanks in Java or .NET. The robot battles are running in real-time and on-screen.

Comment: My one complaint about RoboCode is that it quickly turns into a trig learning project rather than an API or AI learning project.  Once you develop a set of libraries to abstract away the trig you can get to work programming the AI.  IMHO it should come with such a library as part of the API.

Comment: RoboCode is great fun.  I used to work for a company where we'd have in-house team battles on away-days.  You'd have to develop your robot using TDD and check the code into SVN.  Every 20 minutes CruiseControl would check out the latest code, run the unit tests (I think you had to have a certain percentage of code coverage as well) and launch a battle on a projected screen.  You'd half watch the battle while improving your robot for the next round 20 minutes later.  Great fun.

Answer (score 10):

You may want to check out AIIDE in 2010, where they will be hosting a [Starcraft Broodwar AI competition](http://eis.ucsc.edu/StarCraftAICompetition). You can download the software, API, and proxies to allow you to connect your homegrown AI into the Broodwar simulation.

Unlike other platforms such as 3D Robocup, the Broodwar engine will handle the physics, and will probably allow you to focus most of your time on higher level aspects such as path planning, strategy, resource allocation, etc. There are also basic forms of AI that you can plop in as placeholders while you work on your specific improvement, say a melee AI for example.

Comment: +1 nice call, don't know how i didn't remember that one. on a side note: when you say "Unlike other platforms such as Robocup" you're talking about the 3D league since the 2D league is, as Drew Noakes said, "more abstract".

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the 3D league. You're right that the 2D league is more abstract. In the 2D league the basic operators are "move, dash, turn and kick".

Answer (score 9):

Check out [Mario AI](http://julian.togelius.com/mariocompetition2009/). You get to program an AI to control mario. There's a competition and some papers associated with it. Very easy to setup and get running with Java or any JVM language.

Answer (score 6):

My AI class used the open-source [BZFlag](http://bzflag.org/), which turned out to be quite entertaining and informative.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider Open NERO (" (Preferably in Java, but I'm open to any language.)") but it's written in Python. If none of the Java suggestions appeal to you, take a look here:

http://code.google.com/p/opennero/

It doesn't "lack" AI code, it contains it. Perhaps looking at an AI implmentation in Python would give you some inspiration for your Java efforts.

Edit: To address vidstige's comment - you could try this : http://aichallenge.org/ - Programming ants to gather food and fight enemy. There seems to be a Java implementation there.

Comment: does this really answer the question? He's looking for something where you have to fill in the AI your-self...

Comment: @vidstige - good point - original post edited to include something a little more focused on the question.

Comment: @vidstige: It also has exercises which are good for practicing AI algo's. It contains examples from very famous AI book Russell and Norvig's textbook Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach.

Answer (score 2):

You may start with
[this game](http://code.google.com/p/unical-3d-game/)

Some AI is already implemented so that you can take example

Answer (score 2):

I know you indirectly referenced RoboCup in your question, but I think it's worth a mention here given the heading.  There are both 2D and 3D versions:

- [2D League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCup_2D_Soccer_Simulation_League)
- [3D League](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RoboCup_3D_Soccer_Simulation_League)

The 2D league is more abstract with commands like move, catch, kick.

The 3D league is more complex as you have to control the angles of each hinge in a 3D robot's body (22 of them with the Nao model).

Both are equally valid exercises for AI.  It probably depends what area of AI you want to play with.

Both can be programmed from any language/platform that supports TCP sockets.  You'll find sample code in Java online to get you started.  I've been maintaining a list of existing libraries for 3D RoboCup on the [SimSpark Wiki here](http://simspark.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Agents#SimSpark_.26_RoboCup_3D_Libraries).

If you want to use .NET for the 3D league, you can use the [TinMan library](http://code.google.com/p/tin-man) I created.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ORTS](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~mburo/orts/orts.html).

Comment: ORTS is an open-source RTS game framework. You set it up, define the game, and then you write AI agents that use the API to play the game.

Answer (score 1):

[Torcs](http://torcs.sourceforge.net/) is a racing game engine that lets you build your own drivers in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your prof's game reminds me a lot of the old macintosh game [Assassin](http://macintoshgarden.org/games/assassin), which wasted many of my after-school hours back in the day.  It was an interesting turn-based game where players input their moves at the start of each turn, and then their moves are executed simultaneously.   The game's AI's were kind of dumb, and I always wished I could muck around and improve them, but I never found an open source version of the game.